# How to navigate and interact with a HUAWEI P30 Lite with a broken screen using an external keyboard

Tags: backup, settings, keyboard, mouse

I have a HUAWEI P30 Lite with a broken screen, and I'm attempting to save my data. I've connected an external USB keyboard and mouse, as well as inserted an SD card for backup. However, I'm encountering issues when trying to interact with the device.

I can navigate the menu but face problems when I try to select options, such as initiating a backup or toggling settings like Bluetooth. When I encounter a Toggle-Button or a Link-Button (the ones with an arrow on the right), pressing "Enter" on the keyboard or clicking with the mouse doesn't produce any response.

Is there a special shortcut or workaround to effectively interact with these kinds of buttons and do my data backup?

Comment: Is USB Debugging or ADB enabled on the phone by any chance?

Comment: @RajatGupta yes, usb debugging is enabled

Answer (score 1):

In the case of USB Debugging enabled, best way is to install [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) on your computer and connect the phone and launch scrcpy. It will mirror the phone to your PC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but won't I have to confirm the pc's access to the phone for this to work? I am afraid since the screen is broken this will not be possible.

Comment: Yes you are right, if you're doing it for the first time it will require authentication :)